# how to reduce the cost of the below query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r
WHERE
    trunc(creation_date) < trunc(sysdate) - 2
    AND ( ( request_id < (
        SELECT
            MAX(xcs_sub.request_id)
        FROM
            xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r xcs_sub
        WHERE
            xcs_sub.status = 'PROCESSED'
            AND xcs_sub.file_id = 'CBS1330'
    )
            AND file_id = 'CBS1330' )
          OR ( request_id < (
        SELECT
            MAX(xcs_sub.request_id)
        FROM
            xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r xcs_sub
        WHERE
            xcs_sub.status = 'PROCESSED'
            AND xcs_sub.file_id = 'CCI1330'
    )
               AND file_id = 'CCI1330' ) )
```

- explain plan has showing cost = 37061
- I am tried to create index on column which is used in where clause but not working.

Comment: *Cost* only is IMO not the best starting point for tuning. Show the complete [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) and other information about your table (if it is a table and not a view) so that more focused answer can be provided; not a poor guessing.

Comment: We don't know how selective your criteria is. `trunc(creation_date) < trunc(sysdate) - 2` can be optimized to `creation_date < trunc(sysdate) - 2`. And it seems that this will affect almost all rows in the table (all rows except the most current three days). How many days are usually in the table? Then, you only consider file IDs CBS1330 and CCI1330. How many different file IDs are in the table? At last, what percentage of the rows has a status PROCESSED? How many rows des the table have? How many rows do you expect the query to return?

Comment: The 'cost' is just an artificial number that the optimizer uses to compare the expected performance of several possible access plans for a given statement.  If you query is not running as fast as you'd like, forget about looking at 'cost' and focus on EXPLAIN PLAN, and possibly sql traces to see where the time is going.  And consider just how much it is even possible to squeeze out.  How much effort is   justified to reduce the time by 50%  --  if the query is already runnning sub-second?

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Use an analytic function instead of sub-queries.
- Remove the `TRUNC` from around `TRUNC(creation_date)` as if the truncated date is less than `TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2` then it will also always be true without truncating. This would let the optimizer use an index on the `creation_date` column (rather than requiring a function-based index on `TRUNC(creation_date)`).

Which would give you:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT x.*,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN status = 'PROCESSED'
           AND  file_id = 'CBS1330'
           THEN request_id
           END
         ) OVER () AS max_processed_cbs,
         MAX(
           CASE
           WHEN status = 'PROCESSED'
           AND  file_id = 'CCI1330'
           THEN request_id
           END
         ) OVER () AS max_processed_cci
  FROM   xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r x
  WHERE  file_id IN ('CBS1330', 'CCI1330')
)
WHERE  creation_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 2
AND    (  (file_id = 'CBS1330' AND request_id < max_processed_cbs)
       OR (file_id = 'CCI1330' AND request_id < max_processed_cci)
       );
```

Then you can consider adding indexes on the columns you are using.

Comment: after using above query - explain plan showing high cardinality and cost almost same but time will reduce by 2 sec.

Comment: @W_O_L_F The SQL engine will almost certainly treat both equivalently; you can use `EXPLAIN PLAN` to check if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this index (if adding an index is an option in the first place):

```
create index test_index on xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r(file_id, request_id, status)
```

Comment: adding index for file_id, request_id, creation_date and status column has already index is created. After creating index has execute explain plan but cost will not reduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        tr.* 
FROM
    xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r tr
join (
        SELECT
            xcs_sub.file_id, MAX(xcs_sub.request_id) request_id 
        FROM
            xxcpb_i45_06_interface_r xcs_sub
        WHERE
              xcs_sub.status = 'PROCESSED'
          AND xcs_sub.file_id in ('CCI1330', 'CBS1330')
        group by xcs_sub.file_id

    )t on t.request_id > tr.request_id 
      and tr.file_id =  t.file_id
where 
      creation_date < trunc(sysdate) - 2;
```

Comment: thnx, After running this query its taking more time and in explain plan showing cost which is also increased. we want to reduce the cost and time of the query so that its running faster and cost should minimum

Comment: @Aishwarya Add more info about your table.

Comment: What exact info you need to know about table

Comment: @Aishwarya rows num, indexes,  and also need query plan.